# Lambda overloaded method

Tags: java, lambda, interface, functional-programming, java-8

I'm new to lambdas and funtional interfaces. I'm trying to implement a RowListener functional interface (ActiveJDBC ORM) with a lambda but I get a compiler error and I don't really now why.

Here's how the anonymous class old-style looks like:

```
db.find("some query", new RowListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean next(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
db.find("some query", map -> {
        // whatever
    });
```

The error that gives me is:

> The method find(String, Object...) in the type Base is not applicable for the arguments (String, ( map) -> {})

I think it's trying to apply the lambda to an overloaded method of 'find' wich doesn't take a RowListener as an argument, but I'm not really sure why.

Any light you can shed on this would be helpful.

Comment: What does the code for RowListener itself look like in the lambda case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda expression of the form

```
map -> {
        // whatever
    }
```

is not compatible with the functional signature. According to your inner class example code, it has to return a `boolean` value. Hence, it has to be either

```
map -> {
        // whatever
        return false;
    }
```

or

```
map -> /* simple expression, e.g.: */ false
```

In case of overloaded methods, the compiler uses the shape of a lambda expression, i.e. whether it’s *value compatible* or *void compatible* (see [JLS §15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)), to determine which methods are applicable.

Keep in mind that if the lambda’s body is a block containing conditional code, all code flows which can complete normally must return a value.

Since *all* methods are inapplicable, the compiler picks one to report an error, according to an algorithm which is independent of the fact that one argument is a lambda expression. It seems that it reports against the method `find(String, Object...)` because that method can consume most kind of arguments. You could say, that method could consume anything, if there weren’t lambda expressions.

That might be a compiler specific behavior which has been implemented before lambda expressions were to consider. However, that’s only the error reporting behavior, the primary problem is the lambda expression which is not *value compatible*. Fixing it should solve all problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the error message confused me. I added a boolean return value and it compiles :)